3D cylindrical polar plot in python (beamforming per different frequencies)
Is it possible to make this figure in Matplotlib or any other libraries in Python?
The top figure can be easily achieved with plt.polar in mattplo, but how about the bottom one? Would Tikz be more appropriate?

Image taken from the paper "Steering Study of Linear Differential Microphone Arrays"  by Jin, et al.
